# $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^{\beta}} dx < \infty$, where $\alpha > 0$ and $ 0< \beta < 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^{\beta}} dx \in L^{1}(0, \infty)$, where $\alpha > 0$ and $ 0< \beta < 1$.

My idea is to use the fact that

$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^{\beta}} dx = \int^{1}_{0} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^{\beta}} dx + \int^{\infty}_{1} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^{\beta}} dx
$$

I know
$$
\int^{\infty}_{1} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^{\beta}} dx < \int^{\infty}_{1} e^{-\alpha x} dx < \infty
$$
My problem is in showing that
$$
\int^{1}_{0} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^{\beta}} dx < \infty.
$$

Comment: $\int_0^\infty  \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^b}\in L^1(0,\infty )$ is wrong... maybe you wanted to say that $x\mapsto \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^\beta }in L^1(0,\infty )$ ?

Comment: The fact that $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^\beta }\,\mathrm d x<\infty $ comes from the fact that for all $x\in (0,1)$, $$\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^\beta }\leq \frac{1}{x^\beta }\in L^1(0,1).$$

Comment: @Surb Yes! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a very naive way you could observe that

$$\text{as}\quad x\to 1 \quad \frac{e^{-ax}}{x^b} \sim e^{-a}$$
$$\text{as}\quad x\to 0^+ \quad \frac{e^{-ax}}{x^b} \sim \frac{1}{x^b} - ax^{1-b}$$

Whence the integral converges if $\text{Re}(b) < 1$.

Consider also that this integral is well known in literature:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-ax}}{x^b}\ \text{d}x = a^{b-1} \Gamma (1-b)-E_b(a)$$

Where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ denotes the Euler Gamma Function, and $E$ denotes the Exponential Integral Function. This integral does converge for $\text{Re}(b) < 1$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use that $\beta\in(0,1)$: If you integrate by parts once, the $x^\beta$ disappears from your denominator:

$$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x^\beta}dx = \frac{1}{1-\beta}\left([x^{1-\beta}e^{-\alpha x}]_0^1 +\alpha \int\limits_0^1 x^{1-\beta}e^{-\alpha x}dx\right)$$